# Find index of an Id inside list and then delete it using the index in Aura

Tags: aura

.cmp file:

```html
<aura:iteration items="{!v.Files}" var="f" >
    <li>
        <b class="color-blue">{!f.name} </b>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="{!f.documentId}" onclick="{!c.delFilesAction}">Delete</a> 
    </li>
</aura:iteration>
```

Controller file:

```javascript
delFilesAction:function(component,event,helper){
    component.set("v.Spinner", true); 
    var documentId = event.currentTarget.id;
    var filesUploaded = component.get("v.Files");
    var index = filesUploaded.indexOf(documentId);
    filesUploaded.splice(index, 1);
    component.set("v.Files", filesUploaded);
```

Example of file list:

`{name: 'calculator.xml', documentId: '0698D000000CYa8QAG', contentVersionId: '0688D000000CY0SQAW', contentBodyId: '05T8D000001tYHUUA2', mimeType: 'text/xml'}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexVar attriubte of aura:iteration to to assign index. Using this index based on action you can delete element from array.

**app.cmp**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="Files" type="Array"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.Files}" var="f" indexVar="index" >
        <div>
            {!f.name}  - <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="{!index}" onclick="{!c.delFilesAction}">delete</a>
        </div>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

**appController.js**

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        let files = [{name: 'calculator.xml', documentId: '0698D000000CYa8QAG', contentVersionId: '0688D000000CY0SQAW', contentBodyId: '05T8D000001tYHUUA2', mimeType: 'text/xml'},
         {name: 'xyz.xml', documentId: '0698D000000CYa9QAH', contentVersionId: '0688D000000CY0SQAW', contentBodyId: '05T8D000001tYHUUA2', mimeType: 'text/xml'},
        ];
        
        component.set('v.Files', files);
    },

    delFilesAction:function(component,event,helper) { 
        component.set("v.Spinner", true);
        var index = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        var filesUploaded = component.get("v.Files");
        filesUploaded.splice(index, 1);
        component.set("v.Files", filesUploaded);
    }
})
```